# Powershell script for comparing two directories and excluding certain files

Tags: powershell

The short is that I have two external hard drives (labelled T: and V:) along with my primary SSD; I use T: strictly for media storage, and V: should simply be a mirrored backup of that. One twist is that I slightly amend certain file names on T: after a video has been watched by putting a hash in front of it (to signify which video in the list I'm upto). Example: 1. Pilot, #2. Show, 3. Game ... watch ep 2, it becomes: 1. Pilot, 2. Show, #3. Game.

I now have really weak, useless code, sorry. I'm fairly new to Powershell and I don't want anyone to waste their summer's day doing it all, but any suggestions to get me going? Really, I'm focused on any sort of exclusion/ignore provision for files which are 99% comparable; i.e. #2. Show vs 2. Show (I know about the count from left/right function but can't seem to get it to work how I want it to).

Thanks and sorry for the muddled question.

Code atm: `gci -recurse -path C:\V\TV, C:\T | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*.txt*"} | Group -noelement | where {$_.count -eq 1} |  Sort-Object -Property Name`

`Count Name

---

```
1 #Goodbye - Copy (20).txt 
1 #Goodbye - Copy (6).txt  
1 #Hello - Copy (21).txt   
1 #Hello - Copy (7).txt    
1 Goodbye - Copy (20).txt  
1 Goodbye - Copy (6).txt   
1 Hello - Copy (21).txt    
1 Hello - Copy (7).txt`
```

Comment: What part of code is not working as expected?

Comment: bah, formatting my posts wrong... hold on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to know what are the differences between the two, the following script is what you might want:

```
$T = Get-ChildItem T: -Recurse
$V = Get-ChildItem V: -Recurse
Compare-Object $T $V
```

or in its compact form:

```
compare (ls T: -Recurse) (ls V: -Recurse)
```

Please note that it will simply compare every files found under T: and V: 
You can narrow your comparison by some filtering in Get-ChildItem cmdlet.

**EDIT**

update from comment, the following is the script that will list only unique value, stripping filename from starting character `#` , using TrimStart method of `[String]`

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path T:,V: | %{ $_.Name.TrimStart('#') } | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Comment: It's not so much broken as I can't find the right filter. I've setup dummy T and V files with a bunch of txt files in. Here's my code and its output, and what I want is for all of those files to be excluded because they are all the 'same' files, just with that hash in.


`gci -recurse -path C:\V\TV, C:\T | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*.txt*"} | Group -noelement | where {$_.count -eq 1} |  Sort-Object -Property Name`


`1 #Goodbye - Copy (20).txt
1 #Goodbye - Copy (6).txt
1 #Hello - Copy (21).txt
1 #Hello - Copy (7).txt
1 Goodbye - Copy (6).txt
1 Hello - Copy (21).txt
1 Hello - Copy (7).txt`

Comment: @user2567649 put it in your question. There you can format the code.

Comment: Sorry, not getting on well with frickin' formatting on this forum at all! If you can just about make out the code, ending "-PropertyName", and the output is a formatted list, where you can see those almost-duplicates.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer - thanks but it's not what I'm looking for. I've used compare-object and it doesn't fit with any conditions. If I could build on the code in the OP with some sort of command to exclude those files listed if they are basically duplicates, like one character different (hash on the left)...

Comment: In its simplest form, what is the cmdlet for making an exception in the script if the content has two lines whose last 10 characters (as an example) are the same?

So if you have 1. Test Video File and #1. Test Video File, that provision would exclude either item from appearing in the output because the last 10 characters are exactly the same. 

Something to do with $str? Feel like I've learned this before but escapes me!!

Comment: One final note, and a possible alternative: What about using $replace with the #? The only problem is - again - can't get it to behave as I wish. Can't replace # with a blank (''), which means the results still output.

Comment: may I know what is the intent of the 'weak, useless code' mentioned in OP? An input and expected output will be a real help.

Comment: Code is in OP. Input is two drives/directories containing many sub-directories with .avi, .mp4 and .mkv files therein. Expected output is a text list of any unique file names (except those which are different by only 1 character, i.e. a # at the beginning).

Comment: ah, I see. Then what you are looking for is TrimStart('#'). This is the basic, you can insert your own filtering. Hope it helps.

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path T:,V: | %{ $_.Name.TrimStart('#') } | Sort-Object -Unique`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seems to do exactly what I want. Only single line of text in my new output is "New Content File.txt", which is a file I created in a sub-dir of T: but NOT V:. All the "duplicates" have been excluded.

Comment: Please propose as answer or whatever you need to do for me to give you the credit.